# How do I combine multiple delegate calls to IEndpointRouteBuilder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, delegates

In one place of the code I have

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => 
{
    endpoints.MapOneDefaultEndpoints()
    endpoints.MapAnotherDefaultEndpoint()
}
```

and in the startup I want to have

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => 
{
    endpoints.MapOneCustomEndpoint()
    endpoints.MapAnotherCustomEndpoint()
}
```

Reason being I want to hide the default endpoint configuration, so that only the custom endpoints need to be configured. Is there a way to build e.g. a `List<Action<IEndpointRouteBuilder>>` that is then passed on, to be combined with the default configuration?

Answer (score 0):

So I think I've found a solution, which looks like

```
public virtual void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    var customEndpoints = new List<Action<IEndpointRouteBuilder>>
    {
        e => e.MapOneDefaultEndpoints(),
        e => e.MapAnotherDefaultEndpoint(),
    };

    app.UseCustomServices(customEndpoints: customEndpoints);
}
```

And inside my `UseCustomServices` I add the rest of the endpoints

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseCustomServices(this IApplicationBuilder app, List<Action<IEndpointRouteBuilder>> customEndpoints)
{
    customEndpoints.Add(e => e.MapOneDefaultEndpoints());
    customEndpoints.Add(e => e.MapAnotherCustomEndpoint());

    // Register whole list of endpoints
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        customEndpoints.ForEach(ce => ce(endpoints));
    });

    return app;
}
```